# Outline to improve the user experience

Tags: planning

I am working on a project that is basically a search engine for food. It tells you the nearest place that serves the dish you want to eat. They requested me to make a simple outline about our actual goals, how to improve the user experience and where should we be heading.

I came up with this:

> **Questions**
>
> - How specific they are while searching for a dish?
> - In which situation they are more likely to use the site?
> - What’s their screen resolution?
>
> **Personas**
>
> - Desktop user
> - Mobile/Tablet user
> - Person looking for a dish
> - Person looking for a partcular type of food
> - Person looking for top/recommended dishes
>
> **Objectives**
>
> - Finding the dish they are looking for
> - Finding uselful information about the dish/restaurant
> - Finding what other people think about the dishes
>
> **Features**
>
> - Enabling users to like dishes
> - Sorting dishes by number of likes
> - Enabling users to comment the dishes
> - Enabling users to add pictures?
>
> **Problems**
>
> - Logic between dish results and popup menu
> - Displaying the dishes images

This is my first time writing this kind of an outline and I have the following questions:

- It is well organized?
- Am I missing something?
- Should I include something else?

Comment: Its interesting to see a question on the documentation of the development process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've made a great start.

You could condense a lot of your notes by using this structure:

"As a <user type> I want to <activity> so that <goal>"

e.g. "As a mobile/tablet user I want to search dishes so that I can find the dish I'm looking for"

There's an article about this technique here:
http://blog.mountaingoatsoftware.com/advantages-of-the-as-a-user-i-want-user-story-template

One main advantage is that this structure forces you to consider the end goal and limits the tendency to add features just because they seem like a good idea.

Like I say, great start.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I would definitely apply some of your suggestions.

Comment: I think the mobile/table/desktop user should belong to a kind of category though

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I was trying to use your notes to create the example but ideally that would refer to a user type.

Comment: I already made one. But could't post the screenshot here. Here it is: http://www.pixentral.com/show.php?picture=1npueQs5lMKrg4JvtiKIuVuqzdCmD0 what do you think?

Comment: I included two more things: different color backgrounds showing the priorities and added (d/m/t) besides the name of each user (desktop/mobile/tablet).

Comment: Looks good.  This is just the sort of template pros use.  I think you've got a question mark because there may be two kinds of contributor: 'reviewer' and 'business owner'.  Or maybe you've found that the feature isn't useful.

Comment: Good luck with the project and don't forget to do lots of competitor analysis!

Answer (score 0):

I would split the list in to user scenarios and requests then construct user-driven-development statements (as mentioned by Rob - as an X I want to Y) based on the combinations.

A scenario might be something like "mobile user looking for a restaurant near current location", "mobile user searching from home for a restaurant for later" or "desktop user searching for a restaurant now" and a request might be "Find a restaurant close to me", "find a restaurant of a certain type" or "find a restaurant with an average review of n stars or more"

Some examples:

1. As a mobile user looking for a restaurant to eat in now I'd like to
   find restaurants near me which are open right now
2. As a desktop user looking for restaurants to eat in later I'd like to find restaurants
   based on an average review of 5 stars
3. As a desktop user looking for Japanese food I'd like to find Japanese restaurants within 5miles of my location

Answer (score 0):

also a good addition to get the ball rolling is a (non-trivial) list of opportunities and threats...keeping the best out there in mind, like urbanspoon etc. maybe also a much tighter worded executive summary, where you specify what kind of food search engine this is. otherwise you have to spot this information in your lists so far. for example: this food search engine is aimed at regular foodies that regularly look to other foodies likes, combined with their own tastes and preferences. the app/website will make money by...